# What is the easiest way to check if the two CRgn intersects?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I use VS2010 and have:

```
CRgn rRgn1, rRgn2;
```

I'd expected a function like:

```
BOOL CRgn::Intersect(CRgn rRgn);
```

or

```
BOOL Intersect(CRgn rRgn1, CRgn rRgn2);
```

Already had search [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/077zk1zy(v=vs.100).aspx) and [the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CRgn+%5Bmfc%5D+intersect) with no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`CRgn::CombineRgn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3thzd4.aspx) with a parameter of `RGN_AND`. It will return `NULLREGION` if the intersection is empty.